# SSAS 2005 The peer prematurely closed the connection RANDOMLY

Tags: excel, exception, ssas, oledb, adomd.net

SSAS 2005, which was working perfectly for years, is now acting strangely.

After doing a Windows Update, it throws random errors when queried, depending on selected client. It happens with both OleDb and AdoMD.NET drivers.

Here's what I got

> OleDbException (0x80004005): An error was encountered in the transport layer.
>   The peer prematurely closed the connection.

At first Windows Update broke my SPN, so I had to fix it with Kerberos Configuration Manager for SQL Server. Authentication was back in SQL Server Profiler (no more ANONYMOUS LOGON on NTUserName column)

**But the exception, after established connection and some succesful browsing in Excel seems totaly random !**

- Excel 2007, depending on selected members.
- Excel 2013, depending on selected members (other than the ones on Excel 2007).
- Website doing some reports gets 0x80004005 exception as well
- SQL Server Management Studio 2012 is doing OK
- Excel 2007 on server is doing OK

When I use SQL Server Profiler on working MDX, there's nothing special.

> Discover Begin 4 - MDSCHEMA_CUBES
>   Discover End   4 - MDSCHEMA_CUBES
>   Query Begin    0 - MDXQuery
>   Query End  0 - MDXQuery

And a when I choose a special different field (which cause the Exception)

> Discover Begin 4 - MDSCHEMA_CUBES
>   Discover End   4 - MDSCHEMA_CUBES
>   Audit Logout

Cubes are working. They have not changed for years.
Any ideas ?

SQL 2005 : SP4
Windows Server : 2008R2
Clients and server both on the same domain.